# How to format dictionary keys in Python 3x

Tags: python

I am trying to format the dictionary key so that I can ask the user for the value and add that to the dictionary.
so far my dictionary looks like this:

```
{'admin': ' '}
```

Expected output:

```
name: admin
admin's password: admin
```

Code:

```
new dictionary = {'admin': 'admin'}

def example():
        name= input("name: ")
        #no value yet for the input key
        value = ""
        dict_users[name] = value
        check(dict_users)

def check(name):
    if name in dict_users.items():
        password = input('{name}'.format(**dict_users) + "s"+ " Password: "))
        #add password input to existing dictionary key
        dict_users[name] = password

#Dictionary of Users
dict_users = {}
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use string formatting here.

Also, see how you have to test if a key exists in a dict

```
def check(name):
    if name in dict_users:
        password = input(name + "'s"+ " password: "))
        #add password input to existing dictionary key
        dict_users[name] = password
```

Comment: def check(name):
    if name in dict_users.keys():
        password = input(name + "'s"+ " password: "))
        #add password input to existing dictionary key
        dict_users[name] = password

Comment: its not prompting for the password

Comment: nevermind,  I was able to solve my typo. I changed 'if' to 'for'

Comment: Changing `if` to `for` is not a typo. This `check` function takes a name, checks to see if the name is a key in dict_users, and then updates the password. If you change `if` to `for`, then no matter what name you pass to `check`, it will go through and prompt you to change every user's password

Comment: @Python then your typo is elsewhere... dont forget that `name` is case sensitive. If the user name is `Admin` then you have to write `Admin` in the input. `admin` won't be found.